# Server time in jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

How do you set the highlighted date as Server date in jQuery UI Datepicker?

I am using PHP for the server side programming and I have the following code:

```
<script>

    $(function() {
            $("#from45").datepicker({
                //defaultDate: "+1w",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,

            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want the date of your server to be used as the starting date in your datepicker?

Comment: that date should be highlighted in datepicker

Comment: Do you mean the date of the server or the date of the person viewing? It's unlikely that the date would be that different either way...

Comment: Date of the server only highlighted in datepicker

Comment: OK. You'll need a script on your server to send the date to the browser. Which server technology are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP for Server programming!

Comment: OK. I think you need to go and edit your question and add all this information in there!